# Show the function defined on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ via $\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ if $(x,y) \neq 0$ and $0$ otherwise is not integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f: [0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be defined via

$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} &(x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
(0,0) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

So I know if I integrate with respect to $x$ I get

$$\frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}$$

and if I integrate this with respect to $y$ I get

$$-\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$$

which is bounded. How is this function non-integrable? also when integrating w.r.t. $x$ was I supposed to plug in end points $0$ and $1$ before moving onto integrating $y$?

Comment: You have $\int_{[0,1]} \int_{[0,1]} \frac {x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \,dx\,dy \neq \int_{[0,1]} \int_{[0,1]} \frac {x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \,dy\,dx $. One is $\pi/4$ and the other is $-\pi/4$.

Comment: That’s what I thought too! Ok cool! Thanks @RRL cause integrating w r t y you get positive y over $x^2+y^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim that
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dx dy \neq \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dy dx.$$
We compute the LHS:
\begin{align*}
    \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dx dy &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dx dy\\
    &= \int_0^1 -\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \bigg\vert_0^1 dy\\
    &=-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+y^2}dy\\
    &=- \tan^{-1}(y) \bigg \vert_0^1\\
    &= -\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align*}
Now we compute the RHS:
\begin{align*}
    \int_0^t \int_0^1 f(x,y) dydx &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dy dx\\
    &=\int_0^1 \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \bigg \vert_0^1 dx\\
    &= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2+1} dx\\
    &= \tan^{-1}(x) \bigg \vert_0^1 \\
    &= \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align*}
thus $f(x,y)$ is not integrable.

Answer (score 3):

The iterated integrals exist but are not equal (the sign changes depending upon the order of integration).  That is a clue that the function is not absolutely integrable either in the sense of Lebesgue integration or improper Riemann integration. Otherwise Fubini's theorem would imply that the iterated integrals are equal.

For improper Riemann integration over $[0,1]^2$ with $S_{\epsilon} = \{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2: \epsilon^2 \leqslant x^2+y^2 \leqslant 1\}$, we get after changing to polar coordinates

$$\int_{[0,1]^2}\left|\frac{x^2- y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right| \, d(x,y)\geqslant \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{S_{\epsilon}} \left|\frac{x^2- y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right| \, d(x,y) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{r^2|\cos^2 \theta- \sin^2 \theta|}{r^4}r \, dr \, d\theta \\ = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{dr}{r}\underbrace{\int_0^{\pi/2}|\cos^2 \theta- \sin^2 \theta| d\theta}_{= 1}= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} (-\log \epsilon)= +\infty$$

---

Note that the step

$$\int_{S_{\epsilon}} \left|\frac{x^2- y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right| \, d(x,y) = \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{r^2|\cos^2 \theta- \sin^2 \theta|}{r^4}r \, dr \, d\theta,$$

equating a double integral to an iterated integral is justified because the integrand is Riemann integrable over the region $S_\epsilon$ which avoids the singularity at $(0,0)$.

Comment: So could I just argue as you did in the comment above?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame: Yes, but be careful in applying the integration limits.  $\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dx = \int _0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right) \, dx = - \left.\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right|_{x=0}^{x=1} = - \frac{1}{1+y^2}$

Comment: Then the second integration with respect to $y$ gives $\int_0^1 \frac{-1}{1+y^2} \, dy = -\left. \arctan  y\right|_0^1 = - \frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: On the other hand $\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\, dy\right) \,dx = +\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Interestingly, if one fixes $\varepsilon>0$, then the integral on the region $\varepsilon\le r\le R\le 1$, $0\le \phi\le \pi/2$,  we have  $$\int_\varepsilon^R \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2(\phi)-\sin^2(\phi)}{r}\,d\phi\,dr=0$$Taking a limit as $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ yields a value of $0$ for the improper Riemann integral.  So , while the integral fails to exist as a Lebesgue integral, it does exist as an improper Riemann integral defined this way.  Is it a coincidence the value is the averaege of the iterated integrals?  Is the value dependent on the way we excluded the singularity?

Comment: @RRL could you upvote my solution if it works well.